# How do I get phpMyAdmin to connect to a local mysql server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I have my config.inc.php file, and have set my host name to localhost.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what my username/password should be.  Is that something I need to configure on the MySql side?  I tried creating an arbitrary username/password (admin/password), but when I try to log into phpMyAdmin with those credentials, I get an error: (#1045 - Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  (Sorry for the dumb question; I just haven't had to install mysql before.  I've always had a host name / username / password given to me.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have the default privileges in mysql, and how to change them.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/default-privileges.html

Answer (score 1):

root with no password.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';      // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';          // MySQL password (only needed
```

Answer (score 0):

What installation of mysql are you using? Without knowing that its very hard to know. I would recommend getting the wamp installation and remembering that the usual "normal" installation uses user name: root and no password

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, you need to go and look up the password in the config files yourself, since phpMyAdmin's interface will hide the password from you. It's a pain... unfortunately I'm too lazy to install it myself and find exactly where it is for you.